# PEP8: What to do when having several functions in the same line resulting in characters>80?

Tags: python, coding-style, conventions, pep8

For example:

```
connections['default'].get_unified_index().get_index(Tag).update_object(tag).update('default')
```

What's the best option?

This?

```
        connections['default'] \
            .get_unified_index() \
            .get_index(Tag) \
            .update_object(tag) \
            .update('default')
```

This?

```
    connections['default'].get_unified_index().get_index(Tag) \ 
        .update_object(tag).update('default')
```

Other? Of course I'm looking too follow pep8 rules, but also trying to achieve the most readable code possible. Thanks!

Comment: Your lines being too long is often a sign that you're trying to do too much in one statement. How about `tag_idx = connections['default'].get_unified_index().get_index(Tag); tag_idx.update_object(tag).update('default')`?

Comment: I'm working with django, from time to time you come across some messy querysets which are very difficult to resolve within 80 characters!

Comment: Sure. But who says you have to do it all on one line? Split the statement at natural boundaries like I did for your example.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably write it as (note the parentheses and the lack of trailing backslashes):

```
    (connections['default']
        .get_unified_index()
        .get_index(Tag)
        .update_object(tag)
        .update('default'))
```

Either that, or split it into several consecutive statements.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're actually hacking on Python itself, you should feel free to adopt a max line length in excess of 80.

Pep8 actually has the answer to your question, and it's neither of the options you show: break the line inside parentheses, or wrap the whole expression in parentheses so you can break the line at dots.